# Drools LHS check against optional fact

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I need to write a rule in Drools 6.5 that checks for the existence of an event of type A. There is a second class named B which has a field `date`.

While checking for existence of an event `A`, if at least one event of type `B` exists, `A` must happen after the latest `B.date` in order for the rule to fire; otherwise the rule should fire regardless of any `B` events.

Both event types of `A` and `B` have their own explicit timestamp field.

```
when
        // TODO if at least one event of type B exists, A must happen after max(b.date). Otherwise, the rule must fire regardless of any B
        $a : A( ... )
then
    ...
```

How do I perform this check?

EDIT: If no `B` is present in the working memory, and `A` meets the requirements, the rule must fire regardless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will fire for each A meeting the temporal constraint that it should happen after all Bs.

```
$b: B()
not B(this after $b)
$a : A( this after $b )
```

If you want to fire this only once, for any number of As, use `exists` in front of `A` and omit the binding.

Comment: This makes the firing of the rule dependent on at least one `B` to exist. I need this rule to fire whether or not any `B`s are in working memory.

Comment: Add another rule (you can combine the LHS using `or`) requiring the absence of any Bs and an A pattern without the constraint. I cannot add this to the answer since your question doesn't say so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited and clarified the question.